# CHKDSK's been on for four days now, shall I interrupt it?

Tags: windows-10, chkdsk

I've started `chkdsk` four days ago, It apparently will take a couple more four days or more. Shall I interrupt this?

HDD is connected to USB, that's probably why it is so slow, but.. this slow?
[image: chkdsk screenshot]

Comment: Your output looks like there is some USB2HDD controller/interface problems (or a huge surface damage).  Of course, you may interrupt it freely by Ctrl-C. I'd recommend you to remove HDD from the box and connect it directly for checking.

Comment: @Akina Thank you very much, actually I do it by USB because this laptop is Asus and is hard to dismantle, I have a Linux running laptop on which it is easy to connect HDD directly. But After some research I could not find an equivalent of chkdsk on Ubuntu. Do you have any suggestion for Ubuntu, or i'm going to have to make a partition and install Windows on that PC too.

Comment: Look https://askubuntu.com/a/59077 or https://askubuntu.com/a/112161, for example.